# Python: Pillow .paste doesn't work properly with transparent

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, overlay

```
news_corners = Image.open("resources/news_image_corner_1.png")
news_corners = news_corners.convert("RGBA")
news_corners = news_corners.resize((359, 225))

news_first_image_raw = Image.open("resources/news_image_1.png")
news_first_image_raw.convert("RGBA")
news_first_image_raw.resize((359, 225))

news_first_image_raw.paste(news_corners, mask=news_corners)
```

I had
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNU3o.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuooX.png
I got
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIEAh.png

Comment: `convert` and `resize` don't work in-place, they return a new image.